# How to increase width of table dotted vertical line?

Tags: tables, tabu

I would like to separate table columns with dotted vertical lines and this is the best I could do. How can I increase the size of the dots? `!{\vrule width <length>}` doesn't seem to be compatible. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,top=1cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{colortbl,tabu}

\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{F1760E}{HTML}{F1760E}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\taburulecolor{F1760E}

\begin{table}[h!]
\makebox[\linewidth]{
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabu}{p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth}}

    1 & (A) &
    2 & (B) &
    3 & (C) &
    4 & (D) \\

    5 & (E) &
    6 & (F) &
    7 & (G) &
    8 & (H) \\

    9 & (I) &
    10 & (J) &
    11 & (K) &
    12 & (L) \\


\end{tabu}
}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}` after `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`. Change `2pt` as needed. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashed rule width respects the setting of `\arrayrulewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{colortbl,tabu}

\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{F1760E}{HTML}{F1760E}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%
  \taburulecolor{F1760E}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{8pt}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
  \begin{tabu}{p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth};{1pt/1pt}
             p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.05\linewidth}}
    1 & (A) &
    2 & (B) &
    3 & (C) &
    4 & (D) \\

    5 & (E) &
    6 & (F) &
    7 & (G) &
    8 & (H) \\

    9 & (I) &
    10 & (J) &
    11 & (K) &
    12 & (L) \\
  \end{tabu}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed the packages unnecessary for the example, for maximum usefulness to other readers. Note the `%` I have introduced; you had an additional group, which is not necessary because contents in `\makebox` is processed in a group anyway.